# IPTV Catchup API

Tags: iptv

Tv Archive / Timeshift

Tv Archive links can be buit from the response data of content/live

Supported urls:

```
/link_archive/{archive|stream}/{token}/offset_{offset}.m3u8
/link_archive_nt/{archive|stream}/offset_{offset}.m3u8 (_nt is no token in URL, you can pass token in query param)
/link_archive/{archive|stream}/{token}/{start}/duration_{duration}.{output}
/link_archive_nt/{archive|stream}/{start}/duration_{duration}.{output}
```

archive|stream - tv_archive_id or stream_id

offset - seconds ago (like 3600)

start - timestamp (in formats 'Y-m-d:H-i', 'Y-m-d H:i:s')

duration - in minutes (like 60)

output - (m3u8|ts)

Timestamp is in server time (GMT0)

While we are integrating we getting nothing from it, Any one have any idea on this

We tried all above details but no response.